# May an Ashkenazi wear Yemenite Tzitzith?

Tags: tzitzis, ashkenazi, mesorah-tradition, techeles, yemenite-temani

Many Ashkenazim now wear Tzitzith with Techeleth tied in the tradition of the RaMBa"M.  However, my understanding is that Ashkenazim minimally require a double-knot at the base of the tassle in order for the Tzitzith to be Kosher, regardless of how they are tied after that, while true Yemenite Tzitzith, in the tradition of the RaMBa"M, regardless of whether or not they have Techeleth, have no double-knot at the base. May an Ashkenazi wear Tzitzith tied in the Yemenite tradition?

Comment: Can you [edit] in some sources regarding what Ashkenazim and Teimanim generally hold about the kesher elyon?

Comment: Can you clarify what _t'cheles_ has to do with this question? Aren't you asking only whether _Ashk'nazim_ can wear _tzitzis_ ties with the Yemenite tying scheme?

Comment: @msh210, I'm bringing up a reason why an Ashkenazi might wear Tzitzith with that tying scheme and asking whether that would be acceptable.

Comment: In Israel you will find many people and communities mixing and matching minhagim from different communities.  Is that what you are asking, or are you asking something else?

Comment: @Avi, it's more than Minhag. Maybe. My question is about the criticality, in Ashkenazi Pesak, of the first double-knot, which does not appear in Yemenite Tzitzith.

Comment: Related:http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36387/what-is-the-basic-requirement-for-tzitzit-knots

Answer (score 1):

[Rav Dov Lior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dov_Lior) rules to put Techeleth, he also rules to make double knot in the beginning and then to make ties by Rambam. I've heard this on his lesson on Mishna Berura where he showed his tzitzis tied this way.

From this I conclude that double knot is essential.

Comment: This is the knot above, the OP is asking about the knot after the chulyot.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt I think that you are not correct. From this part of the question: "a double-knot at the base of the tassle in order for the Tzitzith to be Kosher, regardless of how they are tied after that" I understand that he is talking about the knot *above*.

Answer (score 0):

The double knot at the top is midoraisa. That's what fulfills the mitzvah
The other knots developed and became custom. Some are based on the ari z"l and other kabbalistic sources but it doesn't matter if you have that first double knot. A bigger question would be wearing wool or cotton.

http://steinsaltz.org/learning.php?pg=Daf_Yomi&articleId=2302

Comment: Can you [edit] in sources for your claims?