# May one wear Tzitzit of a different minhag?

Tags: tzitzis

May Ashkenazi Jews wear Tzitzit that are made from a Chabad minhag (i.e., two adjacent holes that the strings come from, not one)?

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17390/759